# Is there any reason to use GIT-LFS for large files that are never updated

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

Under github, is there any reason to use GIT-LFS for large files that are never updated? because GIT-LFS is not free and before to activate it I would like to know the advantage to use it on the top of files (mostly pictures) that never change

Answer (score 2):

If you're 100% sure it will **never** change, no there is no real added value.

But if it will be updated, even rarely, there is added value especially if you have to clone it very often and if you have a lot of files like that.

But you should know that there is a limit of 100Mo in Github for a committed file. So if you have one file bigger than that, Github won't allow you to push it and you will have to use git-lfs anyway...

Comment: Thanks, do you know if when we install Git LFS if the 1GB free limit is applied to only the files in the LFS or also on the files in the normal git repository ?

Comment: The Git LFS usage limit for GitHub is only the LFS files.  Thus, if you have 5 GB of data stored using regular Git and 500 MB stored using Git LFS, you'll qualify for the free tier.